# Is the "volatile" keyword word needed in this instance? (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I have the following code that gets initialized as a static variable in a class:

```
public class MyXlet extends Xlet {
   boolean connected = false;
   ...

   void connect() {
      // some code goes here, starts a new thread
      MyXlet.connected = true;
   }

   void disconnect() {
      // some code goes here, the new thread is designed to terminate once connected is false;
      MyXlet.connected = false;
   }
}
```

Let's say I have already run the connect method, which spawns a new thread. The disconnect() method sets "connected" to "false". Is it guaranteed that the thread that was spawned from the connect() method will see that "connected" is no longer equal to "true"? Or will I have to use the volatile keyword on "connected" for this? It is worthy to note that I am using Java 1.4.2.

Comment: Relevant blog post http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it guaranteed that the thread that was spawned from the connect()
>   method will see that "connected" is no longer equal to "true"?

Only if the thread that was spawned from the `connect()` method is the one that sets `connected` to `false`!

The spawned thread will be able to see that `connected` is true after it is started, because starting a thread is a *happens-before* action, and source code also establishes a *happens-before* ordering within a thread.

But, if the parent thread clears the `connected` flag *after* calling `start()` on the spawned thread, the spawned thread is not *guaranteed* to see the change unless you declare the flag as `volatile`.

The main difference between 1.4 and 1.5 behavior is that writing to a `volatile` variable will also flush writes to non-volatile variables from Java 5 onward. (Reading a volatile variable also clears any cached non-volatile variable values.) Since it appears that you only have one variable involved, this change shouldn't affect you.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you should use volatile. This will ensure that when the field's value is updated all threads that check the field will have the updated value. Otherwise you are not ensured that different threads will get the updated value.

Answer (score -1):

Well, even if you don't add the volatile keyword, other threads will be able to read the connected variable. By adding volatile, amongst other things, you make access to the variable synchronous.

Comment: They'll be able to read the variable, but not its "current" value. To put it another way, the time the variable is written and read according the a clock on the wall makes no difference; you have to use memory barriers (like `volatile`) to establish an ordering over events in different threads.